# UserControl. Свойство, отвечающее за создание нового элемента

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Задача такая. Есть UserControl. Он состоит из набора Item и комбобокса, в котором есть набор айтемов для выбора. Но кроме этого в комбобокс можно ввести собственный текст. Так вот, нужно сделать возможность тому, кто внедряет этот контрол, создавать новый айтем на основе введенной строки. Причем, если тип айтемов, например, число, то все должно происходить на автомате (создать число из строки - не проблема), на если тип айтемов - `MyClass`, то должна быть возможность сказать контролу, как создать из строки экземпляр `MyClass`. Как это осуществить через кривые костыли я могу придумать десяток способов. Но как это сделать красиво?